# Inner products with more than two entries

Tags: terminology, inner-products

Is there a generalization for inner products for more than two entries, for instance $\langle x,y,z\rangle = \sum_{i\in I}x_iy_iz_i$? Of course such a product could lose symmetry, $\langle x,y,z\rangle \neq \langle z,x,y\rangle$ so there might be several ways to generalize this notion, but what this called?

Comment: I don't think there is a standard definition for what you are looking for. But there is a notion of multilinear form. You could look at those with three entries satisfying some axioms you want and give those multilinear forms a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a vector space $\Bbb V$ over a field $\Bbb F$, a multilinear map
$$\underbrace{\Bbb V \times \cdots \times \Bbb V}_r \to \Bbb F$$
is a *multilinear form (of rank $r$)*. In the special case $r = 2$, we use the special (probably familiar) term *bilinear form*, and for $r = 3$ you sometimes see the adjective *trilinear* used.

By the universal property, we can canonically extend any such form to a linear map
$$\underbrace{\Bbb V \otimes \cdots \otimes \Bbb V}_r \to \Bbb F,$$
that is, as an element of $(\underbrace{\Bbb V \otimes \cdots \otimes \Bbb V}_r)^* \cong \underbrace{\Bbb V^* \otimes \cdots \otimes \Bbb V^*}_r$; we call an element of this latter tensor product a *(covariant) tensor (of rank $r$)* on $\Bbb V$.

If we require that the multilinear map be symmetric, we use the terms *symmetric multilinear form* (and so for appropriate ranks *symmetric bilinear form* and *symmetric trilinear form*) and *symmetric (covariant) tensor*. If instead we require it be skew, we often use the term *$r$-form*.